# An Integral Substitution for $\int_0^{1} dy \left(\frac{M^2(y)}{\mu^2}\right)^{-\epsilon}$

Tags: integration, logarithms, taylor-expansion, substitution, quantum-field-theory

I have integral (1) as a result from an advanced QFT problem.

$$
\tag{1}
I=
\frac{\alpha}{2\epsilon}
  \int_0^1 dy
  \left(
  \frac{M^2}{\mu^2}
  \right)^{-\epsilon}
  + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)
$$
where $\mu$ and $\epsilon$ are constants and $M$ is a function of $y$ as,
$$M^2 \equiv q^2y(y-1) + m^2$$
I have trying to get it into the format of (2) as I have a solution for this equation,
$$
\tag{2}
\int_0^1
  \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y}}
  (1-zy)^{-\epsilon}
$$

Attempts:

1. Substitution $dy\to dM^2$ : This doesn't give the required square root
2. Substitution $dy\to dM$ : The square root ends up on the wrong side.
3. Logarithmic expansion of integrand: $\left( \frac{M^2}{\mu^2} \right)^{-\epsilon} \approx 1 - 2\epsilon\ln\tfrac{M}{\mu} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$  which looses the required power of $\epsilon$
4. Logarithmic expansion in $M$ as  $\left( \frac{M^2}{\mu^2} \right)^{-\epsilon} \approx \left(1 - \epsilon\ln M \right)(\mu^2 M)^{-\epsilon} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$
5. I have also tried a substitution $dy \to d\ln M$ which failed to produce a square root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, we only want the integration, right? As pointed out, we can expand over $\epsilon$:$$x^{-\epsilon}=1-\epsilon \log x.$$In our case, we have$$x=\frac{q^2 y(y-1)+m^2}{\mu},$$so we get$$\int_0^1 \text{d}y \,(1-\epsilon \log (q^2 y(y-1)+m^2)+2\epsilon\log\mu)= 1+2\epsilon\log \mu +\epsilon f,$$
with
\begin{align*} f & =\left.─\left(\frac{q \left((2 y-1) \log \left(m^2+q^2 (y-1) y\right)-4 y\right)+2 \sqrt{4
   m^2-q^2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{q (2 y-1)}{\sqrt{4 m^2-q^2}}\right)}{2 q}\right)\right|_0^1 \\ &  =\frac{2 \sqrt{4 m^2-q^2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{q}{\sqrt{4
   m^2-q^2}}\right)}{q}+\log m^2 -2.\end{align*}

Comment: I looked a bit closer and this has the correct form and the right substitution give or take a factor. Good effort!